# Switching subtitles of hls on tvOS/swift

Tags: swift, tvos, http-live-streaming, webvtt

I am using AVplayer of swift for my tvOSApp.

When I use default player, subtitles of the video will be shown on "subtitle" bar on top and can easily switch subtitles. 
So, how can I switch subtitles like that, without using the default playback controls?

I have buttons for switching subtitles on the screen and I'd like to switch during target method of these.

Here is my code for AVPlayer.

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: videoUrl)!)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)        
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
player.play()

self.bgMovieLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
self.bgMovieLayer.frame = view.bounds
self.bgMovieLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
self.bgMovieLayer.zPosition = -1
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.bgMovieLayer, at: 0)
```

I am using the video below for a test.
http://184.72.239.149/vod/smil:BigBuckBunny.smil/playlist.m3u8

I read the documents regarding AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem and came into no answer. I would appreciate if someone can help this.

Comment: Look into `AVMediaCharacteristic.legible`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load `availableMediaCharacteristics` first and after that look for `AVMediaCharacteristic.legible`.
Something like this:

```
let asset:AVAsset
let key = #keyPath(AVAsset.availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions)
 asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [key]) {
  var error: NSError? = nil
  let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: key, error: &error)
  switch status {
  case .loaded:
  // Sucessfully loaded, continue processing
  case .failed:
  // Examine NSError pointer to determine failure
  case .cancelled:
  // Loading cancelled
  default:
    // Handle all other cases
  }
}
let subtitlesGroup = asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristic.legible)
```